# Cypress: How can I get the timestamp of when Cypress start to record in headless mode?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I've started to test using Cypress for couple of weeks ago and been wondering if I could get rid of the loading screen from the video.

Is there an way to timestamp when Cypress start up recording in headless mode?

If it's possible then I think can get rid of loading screen by calculating the duration of the start-up time and start time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my experience - the loading window is due to cypress rendering the code of the test and proofreading it, so I doubt you can skip it.

About the timestamp, you should be able to get it with a simple command at the very beginning of the code or in a `before` statement using [date.now()][1]. Here a sample solution:

```
context('customerGroup_membersGetDiscount', () => {
    before(()=>{
        cy.log(Date.now())
    })
    it('customerGroup_membesrGetDiscount', function () {
        //enter test code here
    })
})


  [1]: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-get-timestamp-javascript/
```